# Why do i have a syntax error on pgadmin4(Trigger)?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

this is my code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER sovrapposizione_spettacoli
BEFORE INSERT ON Spettacoli 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
DECLARE 
CURSOR c1 IS SELECT data_e_ora, durata FROM mv_spettacoli_attivi s WHERE s.codice_sala=: NEW.sala; inizio_spettacolo     mv_spettacoli_attivi.data_e_ora%TYPE; durata_spettacolo     mv_spettacoli_attivi.durata
```

now ignore the code after SELECT, but pgadmin gave me a sintax error near "begin", i tried to correct it by deleting begin and declare and replacing it with execute but after that it still gives me a sintax error in CURSOR, can anybody tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

The CREATE TRIGGER syntax does not allow to have direct pl/pgsql code in CREATE TRIGGER statement.

You must call a function or procedure:

```
CREATE [ CONSTRAINT ] TRIGGER name { BEFORE | AFTER | INSTEAD OF } { event [ OR ... ] }
    ON table_name
    [ FROM referenced_table_name ]
    [ NOT DEFERRABLE | [ DEFERRABLE ] [ INITIALLY IMMEDIATE | INITIALLY DEFERRED ] ]
    [ REFERENCING { { OLD | NEW } TABLE [ AS ] transition_relation_name } [ ... ] ]
    [ FOR [ EACH ] { ROW | STATEMENT } ]
    [ WHEN ( condition ) ]
    EXECUTE { FUNCTION | PROCEDURE } function_name ( arguments )
```

Here is a short demo that you can use to adapt your code (the trigger only declares a cursor using the 'new' value of the row being inserted and does nothing more than return 'new': this is needed for a before insert trigger in PostgreSQL).

Source code:

```
create function mytriggerfunc()
returns trigger
language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
 c1 cursor for select * from mytable2 where id2 = new.id1;
begin
 return new;
end;
$$;
\echo
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
BEFORE INSERT ON mytable1 
FOR EACH ROW
execute function mytriggerfunc();
\echo
insert into mytable1 values(1, 'ONE');
\echo
select * from mytable1;
```

Execution with psql:

```
create function mytriggerfunc()
returns trigger
language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
 c1 cursor for select * from mytable2 where id2 = new.id1;
begin
 return new;
end;
$$;
CREATE FUNCTION

CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
BEFORE INSERT ON mytable1 
FOR EACH ROW
execute function mytriggerfunc();
CREATE TRIGGER

insert into mytable1 values(1, 'ONE');
INSERT 0 1

select * from mytable1;
 id1 | col2 
-----+------
   1 | ONE
(1 row)
```

See [PG trigger functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62431053/why-do-i-have-a-syntax-error-on-pgadmin4trigger).

Comment: don't want to bother but can you correct my code? it still gives me an error

Comment: I cannot really correct your code but I have given an example that you can use to adapt your code.